# Returning an EditorTemplate as a PartialView in an Action Result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views, editortemplates

I have a model similar to this:

```
public class myModel 
{
    public ClassA ObjectA {get; set;}
    public ClassB ObjectB {get; set;}
}
```

In my main view, I have tags similar to this:

```
<div id="section1">
    <%=Html.EditorFor(m => m.ObjectA)%>
</div>
<div id="section2">
    <%=Html.EditorFor(m => m.ObjectB)%>
</div>
```

ClassA and ClassB both have Editor templates defined.

I created some JavaScript that makes an Ajax call to reload the section1 div.  I want the action method to return the editor for ObjectA, ClassA.ascx that is in the EditorTemplates folder.

I have the following in my Action method:

```
public ActionResult GetData(int input) 
{
    // Process input here and create modelData

    return PartialView("ClassA", modelData);
}
```

This gives an error because it cannot find the ClassA view.

My solution has been to create a PartialView in the Views folder called "GetData" and my return renders the GetData view.  The GetData view has only one line of code:

```
<%=Html.RenderForModel()%>
```

This does work, but I was wondering if there was a way for an action method to return and editor template?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
return PartialView("~/EditorTemplates/ClassA.ascx", modelData);
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  It still cannot find the template.  However, it appears that it only searched the location "~/EditorTemplates/ClassA.ascx", which I wasn't expecting.

Comment: However, giving the full path from application root does work.  For example, "~/Views/MyView/EditorTemplates/ClassA.ascx".  I didn't know you could do this.

Comment: Is there a way to have the view render the template itself? Say if `modelData` is of type `ClassA`?

Answer (score 28):

Bonus points for gift wrapping:

```
public class CustomControllerBase : Controller
{
    public PartialViewResult EditorFor<TModel>(TModel model)
    {
        return PartialView("EditorTemplates/" + typeof(TModel).Name, model);
    }

    public PartialViewResult DisplayFor<TModel>(TModel model)
    {
        return PartialView("DisplayTemplates/" + typeof(TModel).Name, model);
    }
}
```

Have the controller (called, say, MyController) inherit from CustomControllerBase, and then:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int id)
{
    return EditorFor(new MyViewModel(id));
}
```

The code will be looking for "~/Views/MyController/EditorTemplates/MyViewModel.ascx".

Comment: Any way to attach the newly created object to the parent model's collection property?

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me (*mvc 4*)

```
public ActionResult GetData(int input) 
{
    // Process input here and create modelData

    return PartialView("EditorTemplates/ClassA", modelData);
}
```